# ¿Cómo insertar un caracter en una posición específica dentro de una cadena?

Tags: r, string, regex

Supongamos que tenemos cadenas de caracteres del tipo:

```
text <- c("514", "1205","945","1305")
```

Y queremos lograr el siguiente resultado:

```
"5:14"  "12:05" "9:45"  "13:05"
```

Lo que significa que el caracter `":"` quedará insertado en la tercera posición de adelante hacia atrás de nuestra cadena. Una forma de lograrlo empleando `substr` y posteriormente `paste0` es la siguiente:

```
uno <- substr(text,(nchar(text)+1)-2,nchar(text))
dos <- substr(text, 1, c(1,2))
tres <- paste0(dos, sep=":", uno)
tres
[1] "5:14"  "12:05" "9:45"  "13:05"
```

Básicamente me interesa optimizar el código porque intuyo que con expresiones regulares se puede alcanzar el mismo resultado. Sin embargo, no he encontrado ninguna respuesta (ni aquí ni en SO en inglés) que se ajuste a las necesidades de este problema específico.
Agradezco cualquier orientación al respecto.

Answer (score 1):

Es posible, aunque no la consideraría más óptima que tu propia solución, tal vez más simple de leer eso sí:

```
text <- c("514", "1205","945","1305")
re <- '(\\d{1,2})(\\d{2})'
gsub(re, '\\1:\\2', text)
[1] "5:14"  "12:05" "9:45"  "13:05"
```

El patrón que usamos, es uno de captura, es decir que nos permite "extraer" por partes la cadena coincidente:

- `(\\d{1,2})` primer grupo, match de 1 o 2 dígitos
- `(\\d{2})` segundo grupo, match de 2 dígitos

Capturando cada grupo, luego hacemos un sustitución mediante `\\1:\\2`, es decir, el primer grupo + `:` + segundo grupo.

Answer (score 1):

Para hacerlo con expresiones regulares utilizamos la librería  **stringr** :

```
library("stringr")

text <- c("514", "1205","945","1305")

text_nuevo <-str_replace(text,"(\\d*)(\\d{2})","\\1:\\2")
cat(text_nuevo)
```

Resultado:

```
5:14 12:05 9:45 13:05
```

La expresión regular (\d*)(\d{2})  estamos indicando que extraiga dos grupos : Un grupo  con uno o más  digitos  anteriores a los dos últimos y otro grupo con los dos ultimos. Así tenemos el grupo 1 y el grupo 2. Luego solo reemplazos: \1:\2.